# If $\mathcal C$ has amalgamation, does $Ind(\mathcal C)$ have amalgamation?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Recall that a category $\mathcal C$ has *amalgamation* if every span admits a cocone. If $\mathcal C$ has amalgamation, then does $Ind(\mathcal C)$ have amalgamation?

The "obvious way to show this" would be to induct on the presentability ranks of objects being amalgamated, presenting them as colimits of chains of objects of lower presentability rank. But this doesn't work -- it seems one can only prove amalgamation over finitely-presentable objects this way (i.e. for a span $B \leftarrow A \to C$ where $A$ is finitely-presentable, there is a cocone). **EDIT** and maybe not even that! See the comments

So I suspect the answer is *no*. But I don't have a counterexample.

Note that if $\mathcal C$ has *functorial* amalgamation, then something like the above proof attempt should work to show that $Ind(\mathcal C)$ does too. But I don't want to assume that amalgamation is functorial.

Comment: Just a small comment, I believe that if Ind(C) is locally multipresentable you can still do it. Multipresentable categories where morphisms are monos correspond to UAECs.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I assume that AEC stands for abstract elemetnary class -- but what's the U?

Comment: The U stands for Universal.

Comment: Do you remember how you proved amalgamation over finitely-presentable objects? I can only do it when $B$ and $C$ are colimits of chains of objects of $\mathcal{C}$. If so, I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051331/a-special-case-of-amalgamation-in-mathrmind-mathcalc).

Comment: @Idéophage lemma: any object X in Ind C which is not finitely presentable is a retract of the colimit of a smooth chain of objects X_i of lower presentability rank. Chain means the colimit is indexed by and ordinal $\lambda$ and smooth means that the functor $i \mapsto X_i$ preserves colimits. With this amalgamation over objects in C becomes an easy induction on the presentability rank of the objects you’re amalgamating. Sorry for the bad formatting I’m on mobile right now, let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: The problem I have is when I do the induction and I am at step $\omega$, I have to amalgamate over something that is not finitely presented anymore. Don't you have this problem too? If the amalgamation is functorial, it works but otherwise I don't see how...

Comment: @Idéophage I answered at your MSE question. It is indeed a bit subtle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A counterexample is given in the paper *Disjoint Amalgamation in Locally Finite AEC* by Baldwin, Koerwien, and Laskowski  [(link).](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/disjoint-amalgamation-in-locally-finite-aec/74050B19FF648BBC596C7A2C8423CB56) They're actually interested in finding AECs in which amalgamation holds for models up to size $\aleph_k$ but not for models of size $\aleph_{k+1}$ for $k\in \omega$. Since you're interested in (essentially) a special case of this,  I'll give a slightly simpler version of their construction, which is itself based on an earlier construction by Laskowski and Shelah ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9301210)). Of course, there might be a much simpler purely categorical example.

Consider the first-order language $L = \{f_n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, where the $f_n$ are binary function symbols. Let $K$ be the class of all finite $L$-structures which contain no independent subset of size $3$, i.e. such that there is no triple $(a,b,c)$ such that $a\notin \langle b,c\rangle$, $b\notin \langle a,c\rangle$, and $c\notin \langle a,b\rangle$, where $\langle X\rangle$ is the substructure generated by $X$.

Now consider the category $\mathcal{C}$ whose objects are $K$ and whose arrows are embeddings between structures in $K$.

**Claim:** $\mathcal{C}$ has the amalgamation property.

Suppose $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon A\to C$ are embeddings between structures in $K$, and identify $A$ with $f(A)\subseteq B$ and $g(A)\subseteq C$. Let $D$ be the disjoint union of $B$ and $C$ over $A$. To make $D$ into an $L$-structure we just need to define $f_n(b,c)$ when $b\in B\setminus A$ and $c\in C\setminus A$. Enumerate $D$ as $d_0,\dots,d_m$, set $f_n(b,c) = d_n$ for $n\leq m$ and $f_n(b,c) = b$ for $n>m$. Then $D\in K$, since for any triple $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ either all $d_i$ are contained in $B$ or all $d_i$ are contained in $C$, in which case the triple is not independent by hypothesis, or we have WLOG $d_1\in B\setminus A$ and $d_2\in C\setminus A$, in which case $d_3\in \langle d_1,d_2\rangle$ by construction.

**Claim:** $\mathsf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ does not have the amalgamation property.

We can identify objects in $\mathsf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ with $L$-structures such that every finitely generated substructure is in $K$ and arrows in $\mathsf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ with embeddings between such structures.

Now it's possible to find an infinite structure $A$ and extensions $B$ and $C$, all in $\mathsf{Ind}(\mathrm{C})$, with elements $b\in B\setminus A$ and $c\in C\setminus A$, such that $\langle Ab\rangle\subseteq B$ is not isomorphic over $A$ to a substructure of $C$, and similarly $\langle Ac\rangle\subseteq C$ is not isomorphic over $A$ to a substructure of $B$. That is, the quantifier-free type of $b$ over $A$ is not realized in $C$, and vice versa.

Now suppose there is an amalgamation $D$ of $B$ and $C$ over $A$, and pretend all embeddings are inclusions. Then we must have $b\in D\setminus C$ and $c\in D\setminus B$. Since $\langle b,c\rangle$ is finite, there is some $a\in A\setminus \langle b,c\rangle$. Then $(a,b,c)$ is independent. Indeed, $\langle a,b\rangle\subseteq B$, so $c\notin \langle a,b\rangle$, and $\langle a,c\rangle\subseteq C$, so $b\notin \langle a,c\rangle$. It follows that $\langle a,b,c\rangle\notin K$, so $D$ is not in $\mathsf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I suppose it doesn't matter in a functional language, but out of curiosity, by "embedding", do you mean "injective homomorphism", or rather "strong embedding" (i.e. quantifier-free-elementary)?

Comment: You're right that it doesn't matter in a functional language. The standard usage in model theory is embedding = quantifier-free elementary = preserves literals (atomic and negated atomic formulas)